# I want to create my own Ubuntu Phone Preinstalled touch image

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to create my own Ubuntu Phone Preinstalled touch image for an android phone. Preferably for a phone that is not supported yet. I'm a newbie to this type of stuff but as a computer engineering student think the learning experience will be very valuable. Are there any resources "books, online tutorials ..." available that can get me started?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this as an answer now instead of a comment.

If you want to port Ubuntu Touch to a new phone, you can do that with a little bit of work porting to any phone which has CyanogenMod 10.1 already built for it.

There is a guide on porting Ubuntu Touch here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting

There is a list of devices which already have ports here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

If the device does not already have CyanogenMod 10.1, then porting Ubuntu Touch will be a lot harder, as you will have to port CyanogenMod as well. You will probably want to stick to devices which already have CM on them unless you have advanced knowledge in kernels.